# How to assign Windows process to specific network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, process

I would like to start specific applications for example MQTT broker, Node-red etc. in multiple instances and I would like to assign, that each one can communicate just on the specific network adapter on Windows.

So it mean, I have many network adapters and each instance of some process can use just own adapter.

Its possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any native tool to do this. Generally, you would configure the application itself, assuming that the vendor/dev has written it in such a way to allow selective binding. Without that, an app will listen on all IPs (and thus all NICs), and send traffic out the best adapter for the destination IP.

I'll note that MQTT broker is written with this already - in the config file, you can specify your listener settings, including bound IP.

I'm not familiar with Node-Red, but a couple minutes googling [shows it has a similar parameter](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/configuration#runtime-configuration) in its runtime setting, `uiHost`

> the interface to listen for connections on. Default: 0.0.0.0 - all IPv4 interfaces.

So in those cases, I would use what the software can already do. For applications that don't support this capability, there's 3rd party apps like ForceBindIP.

Comment: HI, Thanks a lot. I will need to check. The NR and MQTT was just a few examples. My goal is to be able to use it for any king of program. So I will study the ForceBindIP, it looks promises. Thanks for recommendation.